# How to save a new value to a variable outside an async function, inside that async function?

Tags: python, asynchronous

When using an asynchronous function I can access variables outside of the function.

```py
outside_variable = 'some message'

async def printing():
    print(outside_variable)

await printing()
```

But if at any point within the function I assign that outside variable to a new value, the program now believes the variable is localized the function only, and if that assignment is after the usage of the variable, it throws an error.

```py
outside_variable = 'some message'

async def printing():
    print(outside_variable) # <- Using variable 'outside_variable' before assignment  pylint(used-before-assignment)
    outside_variable = 'a new message'

await printing()
```

How can I assign the outside variable with a new value without changing the variables localization? I would like to do it with out the return function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are modifying an outside value inside a function, you have to remember to inform the interpreter of the global variable. using `global variable_name` inside the function. That way you can modify and/or access its contents knowing that the scope of the variable is correct.

```
async def printing():
   global outside_variable
   //Do stuff
```

In addition, remember that when working in asynchronous contexts, you should be sure that you will write/read in a way that you will never lose data.

Comment: Thank you for this, so this means that this is applicable to all functions and not just async functions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, keep in mind that it's a best practice to only use globals where absolutely necessary, such as in some asynchronous contexts.